# PHPStorm and Compass Watch error

Tags: phpstorm, compass-geolocation

I've just made the switch from NetBeans to PHPStorm, and while I'm mostly enjoying the change, I've started to get an error pop-up from time to time on my compass watch routine (which I run directly on the command line):

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["131"] of /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/tree.rb: No such file or directory - /srv/www/c-nbuilding.co.uk/scss/application.scss
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

This seems to happen every now and again when I hit the save button on whatever file it is complaining about (i.e. in this case, `application.scss`), and that file does indeed exist, meaning as soon as I restart the watch process (which I do by running `compass watch --debug-info`), it carries on as usual.

This doesn't happen all the time, but it happens enough for it to become annoying, especially when my console window is behind something else, meaning I don't notice that it has failed, leaving me sat there, refreshing the screen, waiting for the change to pop up.

Comment: Try v6 (EAP stage ATM) -- it has '''File Watchers''' plugin that will call compiler (or whatever you configure) from IDE when file is saved, so no need to use any other watcher. See this blog entry for details: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/

Comment: That file watchers option looks interesting, and I'll take a look into that at some point in the future - but for now, a bit of further investigation has revealed a "safe write" option which I think was causing the issues. This can be disabled by going to File > Settings > (IDE Settings) General and unticking "safe write".